# What design pattern is to be used in JAVA?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a set of inputs and the there are different methods which accept those inputs and do different task in once class. Shall I use a factory pattern here since the method signature is same and create different classes where the implementation differs? The number of cases are pretty big , factory pattern is good idea?

As example I have a switch on file type and there are almost 20 types of file types so 20 switch cases. Have a look at the below example for 2 such cases , I have such 20+ cases

```
switch( fileType ) {
                case SIMPLE_FILE:
                    processSIMPLEData( stepInput, stepOutput,ackFilePath, errorFilePath );
                break;
                case MUL_FILE:
                   processMULData( stepInput, stepOutput,ackFilePath, errorFilePath );
                break;
```

....

Comment: A short example of your domain objects and some code would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the problem statement, please have a look.

Comment: @PRASANTA Take a look at the [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern). This question is more suited for programmers.stackexchange though.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat True, didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

Yes use a factory pattern. Above a **Map** from *file type* to *file type handler* would make sense. Seeing the many parameters, which is a "code smell" as those must be handled everywhere to some degree, it would also be better to offload this in a parameter class, or builder pattern (that can alert when a non-existent feature is parametrised).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,yes offloading the parameters to a parameter class is a great suggestion.But my concern is if I write factory pattern for all these 20+ use cases , where more can also be added , I need to write 20+ classes to write the actual implementation. Any suggestion there?

Comment: A good base class(es). But if you have that much cases, say with business logic, if-statements galore, then declarative definitions are wonderful. Say XML. "process..." is a bit of a nonamer. So I cannot judge the situation. Refactoring could be done incremental.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve. Design patterns state motivation and applicability, and your question doesn't answer this because it is lacking context. What problem are you trying to solve?

From the code above, it seems that you have a processing functionality that depends on the filetype. A simple option would be to have a class-hierarchy for the file types and add a method process which is overridden for the different filetypes. For creation, you need a mapping between filetype and the classes. This could be a factory, but the factory solves another problem namely that the users can create objects without knowing the concrete type. So instead of writing `File f = new SpecificFileType()`, you query a new instance from the factory and get an object of some type you don't know and care about.

If you have a hierarchy of filetypes and want to be able to extend this with operations on the files you should look into Visitor.

Comment: Currently the same signature is used by different methods and they are all doing different stuff , my question is "is it the right way" or I should have better approach here?

Comment: With only "same signature is used by different methods and they are all doing different stuff" being the only information I would say go with a class hierarchy for filetypes. Design patterns solve problems on a different level, and it will be hard to give advice without further context.